# How to check internet connection on android application? [EDITED]

Tags: android, connection

Can you help me?
I have a webView application, and i wat check network connection when on my site clicked a button and its opening new site.
Is this possible?
Sorry i asked bad question first, but thanks for the answear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public  boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) MyApplication.getAppContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo nInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if(nInfo!=null && nInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Simplly call this function and get connection status as Boolean

Comment: MyApplication is MainActivity? or what is going to there?

Comment: you just need the context there, I placed my context to MyApplication so that I can use it from anywhere..

Comment: Please let me know is my answer helped you or not :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getActiveNetworkInfo()`method of `ConnectivityManager` like in the following example:

```
final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = ((ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE));
boolean isConntected = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
```

You need also a permission to do it (in manifest):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: What is context its not declarated.

Answer (score 0):

**Determine if You Have an Internet Connection**

```
    Context context = getApplicationContext();

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
```

Comment: What is context its not declarated.

Comment: you can use getApplicationContext()